# Clickonce deploy problem with IIS 7

Tags: iis, deployment, iis-7, clickonce

I have a "ClickOnce" application that deploys without any problems from a Win2K3 server and IIS 6.

But the same application fails to be deployed from a Windows Server 2008/IIS7, I receive a 404 file not found (on a .config file and not on one of the manifest files) during the installation on a client machine.

In the IIS the mime types .application, .deploy and .manifest are declared correctly, the virtual folder has read & script only execution permissions and it uses the classic .NET AppPool.

What I’m missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research I found this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942045) and found that the .config file extension didn't have permissions. I followed the instructions on the [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942045) and everything work fine.